# ES6 Generator Yield inside arithmetic operation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

When I have this kind of generator defined

```
function *process() {
  let value = 4 * (yield 42)
  console.log(value)
}
```

and I run it:

```
let it = process()
```

`it` variable obtains the iterator in paused state. Then I call

```
it.next()
```

to run body of generator till `yield` statement. Then I call `.next()` once again to resume generator function, passing 10 as argument to it

```
it.next(10)
```

It was the last `yield` in the iterator, so as I understand, second `.next()` call with `10` put `10` in place of `yield`, resulting in `4 * (10 42)`, evaluating this is console yields `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`, but when running the code

```
 function *process() {
      let value = 4 * (yield 42)
      console.log(value)
    }
let it = process()
it.next()
it.next(10)
```

It results in `40`.

**How does this is being interpreted starting from moment after second `.next(10)` call? Why it logs `40`?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EURECA! `yield 42` means that on the first `.next()` call we will receive `{value: 42, done: false}` as result (as seen in the image in the end of the question), so basically this acts as return statement, and when we call `.next(10)` second time there is no `yield 42` in code anymore, but we put `10` in place of all this `yield 42`.

I believe chapter in documentation that describes this is [this](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatorresume), namely step 10 of the algorithm:

> Resume the suspended evaluation of genContext using
>   NormalCompletion(value) as the result of the operation that suspended
>   it. Let result be the value returned by the resumed computation.